# Conditional dropna() pandas

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I have a rather simple question: I want to drop rows from a DataFrame based on a condition. The DataFrame looks something like this:

```
Program        act
Original RO     A
Original RO    nan
Followup RO     B
Followup RO    nan
Integral RO    nan
```

I want to delete nulls for `Original RO` and `Integral RO` Programs only. So it should look like this:

```
Program        act
Original RO     A
Followup RO     B
Followup RO    nan
```

I always have problems when trying to do some operations on a portion of my dataframe and keep the rest as is.

I tried this:

```
df.loc[df.Program.str.match('^(Original|Integral)')] = df.dropna()
```

But isn't working. What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check conditions with [`isin()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`isna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.isna.html) and subset the dataframe.

```
lst = ['Original RO', 'Integral RO']

df = df[~(df['Program'].isin(lst) & df['act'].isna())]

# Another one using drop.
# df = df.drop(df[(df['Program'].isin(lst) & df['act'].isna())].index)

print (df)

       Program  act
0  Original RO    A
2  Followup RO    B
3  Followup RO  NaN
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter `subset` in the call to [`dropna()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html):

```py
df.dropna(subset=cols, inplace=True)
```

where `cols` is the name of column you want to check (to drop the line).